# Python: Is it possible to only have specific modules from a folder in your sys.path

Tags: python, python-module, pythonpath

There are only one or two modules which I need from the a folder which contains several other python modules.  When I add the folder to my path, I effectively make all the modules in that folder available to me.  But there are several outdated modules which I do not want.  Is it possible to only make a certain subset of those modules available to me?

Comment: Don't import the outdated ones?

Comment: Move the outdated ones to another folder?

Comment: Linux, ubuntu to be specific.  I do not have sudo permission on this machine.

Answer (score 2):

Reading your question I understand that

1. You are including the folder in your pythonpath because you need couple of modules from it.
2. As it contains some other modules which may be outdated compared to the version you are using, you do not want to end up importing the wrong library.

I would suggest two options which might work for you.

1. Ensure that this folder you are including is at the end of `sys.path`. This would ensure that any modules that you are already importing if present in the newly included folder is never imported from that particular location.
2. (Only for *nix) Create another folder, and create a symlink to the files you are interested in. You should then include that other folder that you created.

Reading your comment, I would suggest, the best option would be to add the following lines somewhere in your script but before you import`

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/whatever')
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am asking.  Is there anyway to ensure that the folder I'm including is at the end of sys.path?

For example, is there a clear order of when directories in PYTHONPATH are added?

Comment: @ChristopherDorian: How are you planning to add the path to sys.path? If you clarify that it would be easier to answer. One obvious way would be `import sys\nsys.path.append("/whatever")`. This would ensure that your library is at the end of the search path. Is there any other way you are doing?

Comment: Right now, I've been using PYTHONPATH to add the folder.  So far it appears below my own local libraries in sys.path, but I'm not sure if this will always be the case.

Comment: @ChristopherDorian: Have a look into [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables) reference in the document. It says, the default search path is installation dependent. So your best safe bet is what I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Is there an equivalent to PYTHONSTARTUP that I could add those lines to?  It might be cumbersome for me to add those two lines to every python file I run.

Answer (score 1):

If you

```
import X
```

you **only** import the module X. Nothing else. Something being on your python path is not equivalent to being automatically imported (it's just *importable*). See also:

- http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm
- http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: I actually mean available to import, not actually import.  For example, I have a personal installation of numpy in a virtualenv and there's an outdated version on the system globally.  I only want PyQt from the global library but I don't want to risk having the older version of numpy conflicting with the global version.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new directory. For each module you want to import, add a symbolic link (`ln -s`) pointing to the real module. Then add the new directory to your path, and you won't have to play games with your include order.

```
mkdir ./mymods
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH":`pwd`/mymods 
cd mymods
ln -s ../allmods/module1.py 
ln -s ../allmods/module2.py
```